# Unable to log in with AD credentials

Tags: ssh, authentication, samba, fedora

I have a DC (Debian) that seems to be working fine.  I am able to join the domain but when I join a Fedora member it joins but the DNS isn't registered.  I have to manually add the record to the dc.  The Debian members join just fine.  I am also able to ssh and log in to the Debian members using the desktop gui.  I am not able to do either with the Fedora member.  Only local users can log in (ssh/gui).

**/var/log/audit/audit.log**

```
type=CRYPTO_SESSION msg=audit(1636214847.520:2087): pid=32861 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=kernel msg='op=start direction=from-server cipher=chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com ksize=512 mac=<implicit> pfs=curve25519-sha256 spid=32862 suid=74 rport=34444 laddr=10.0.0.17 lport=22  exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=? addr=10.0.0.16 terminal=? res=success'UID="root" AUID="unset" SUID="sshd"
type=CRYPTO_SESSION msg=audit(1636214847.522:2088): pid=32861 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=kernel msg='op=start direction=from-client cipher=chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com ksize=512 mac=<implicit> pfs=curve25519-sha256 spid=32862 suid=74 rport=34444 laddr=10.0.0.17 lport=22  exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=? addr=10.0.0.16 terminal=? res=success'UID="root" AUID="unset" SUID="sshd"
type=USER_AUTH msg=audit(1636214851.295:2089): pid=32861 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=kernel msg='op=PAM:authentication grantors=? acct="test" exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=10.0.0.16 addr=10.0.0.16 terminal=ssh res=failed'UID="root" AUID="unset"
type=CRYPTO_KEY_USER msg=audit(1636214857.117:2090): pid=32861 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=kernel msg='op=destroy kind=session fp=? direction=both spid=32862 suid=74 rport=34444 laddr=10.0.0.17 lport=22  exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=? addr=10.0.0.16 terminal=? res=success'UID="root" AUID="unset" SUID="sshd"
type=CRYPTO_KEY_USER msg=audit(1636214857.117:2091): pid=32861 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=kernel msg='op=destroy kind=server fp=SHA256:3f:a3:9d:94:52:57:d5:43:b1:ed:67:07:77:62:db:05:80:10:1b:b0:57:ab:77:56:88:b8:2a:f2:ef:3e:d3:73 direction=? spid=32862 suid=74  exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'UID="root" AUID="unset" SUID="sshd"
type=CRYPTO_KEY_USER msg=audit(1636214857.122:2092): pid=32861 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=kernel msg='op=destroy kind=server fp=SHA256:3f:a3:9d:94:52:57:d5:43:b1:ed:67:07:77:62:db:05:80:10:1b:b0:57:ab:77:56:88:b8:2a:f2:ef:3e:d3:73 direction=? spid=32861 suid=0  exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'UID="root" AUID="unset" SUID="root"
type=USER_LOGIN msg=audit(1636214857.122:2093): pid=32861 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=kernel msg='op=login acct="(unknown)" exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=? addr=10.0.0.16 terminal=ssh res=failed'UID="root" AUID="unset"
```

**/etc/ssh/sshd_config**

```
Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no 
UsePAM yes 
X11Forwarding yes
PrintMotd no 
PasswordAuthentication yes 
AllowGroups "domain users"
```

**/etc/pam.d/sshd**

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth       substack     password-auth
auth       include      postlogin
account    required     pam_sepermit.so
account    required     pam_nologin.so
account    include      password-auth
password   include      password-auth
# pam_selinux.so close should be the first session rule
session    required     pam_selinux.so close
session    optional     pam_krb5.so minimum_uid=1000
session    optional     pam_winbind.so
session    optional     pam_sss.so
session    required     pam_loginuid.so
# pam_selinux.so open should only be followed by sessions to be executed in the user context
session    required     pam_selinux.so open env_params
session    required     pam_namespace.so
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so force revoke
session    optional     pam_motd.so
session    include      password-auth
session    include      postlogin
```